# Unable to connect to university WPA2 enterprise wifi

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, wpa2-eap

I am using NetworkManager on arch to connect to my university WiFi. I used nm-connection-editor to create the connection. Here is the config:

```
id=ESSID
uuid=b18a2b1c-02f6-48cd-a49d-a91e95cb80ed
type=wifi
interface-name=wlan0
timestamp=1694114242

[wifi]
bssid=80:8D:B7:57:E4:81
cloned-mac-address=random
mac-address=MAC_ADDRESS
mode=infrastructure
ssid=SSID

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[802-1x]
anonymous-identity=anon@SCHOOL.edu
domain-suffix-match=SCHOOL.edu
eap=peap;
identity=SCHOOL_EMAIL
password=PASSWORD
phase2-auth=mschapv2

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=auto
```

When I use iwctl to connect to the network, I get `Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: Failed to determine AP security information`.
I selected no CA certificate required, and I know I don't because my phone worked without one either. What am I doing wrong? Let me know what other information to put here if needed.

Comment: Does [how to connect to wpa2/peap/mschapv2 w/no ca certificate without wpa_supplicant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/754387/100397) answer your question?

Comment: Generally NetworkManager does all the management on it's interfaces, you don't activate wpa_supplicant, iwctl, or ifupdown yourself, you do it all through NetworkManager.  You should try using a NetworkManager UI, like plasma-nm, or Gnome's settings, or NMCLI, or even the D-Bus interface to activate this profile.

Comment: That thread had a different problem than me. I'd rather not install something like plasman-nm because it brings all of KDE along with it, same with gnome. I've tried nmtui and it produces the same error.

Comment: I think the best approach is to try to connect via live linux distribution e.g. like slax (or any other you like) and try to connect via the gui tools which make the life simplier.  This is to see if there is actually a way to connect without any certificates.

Comment: If I am able to, what would be my next step?

Comment: Please use my @ nick when asking a question.  It will show at my message bar.  You can reverse engineer the connection and see what works.